# Using between in QueryDSL for date parameters

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

I am using QueryDSL with jpa and i want to find records between date range somethig like this

```
query.from(timeSheet)
              .where(timeSheet.date.between(fromDate, toDate)).fetch();
```

but between only supports boolean and String expressions

Comment: Try cast(fromDate as date) 
                       and cast(toDate as date). Querydsl not provide datediff functions

Comment: non elegant `gt and lt` can be effectively executed on DB. Comparator probably fetch zillion of rows into client (client side filtering) EDIT one minute later: I had writing in context of diferent @Priyesh comment

Comment: gt , lt , goe, loe either takes boolean or string expression

Comment: What version of `QueryDSL` do you use? What's the type of `query`? Is it a `JPAQuery`?

Comment: @PriyeshMishra I'm surprised to poor support date types.

Comment: @MehdiJavan here you go <dependency>
  <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.6</version>
</dependency>

Comment: @PriyeshMishra So, it's a `JPAQuery`. I believe arguments types of `between` method for `DatePath` are `Date` or `Expression<Date>`. What's the type of `date` in `TimeSheet`?

Answer (score 0):

```
query.from(timeSheet)
              .where(timeSheet.date.between("today >= fromDate AND today <= toDate")).fetch();
```

try somthing similiar to this.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. all date are in `LocalDate` formate.

```
JPAQueryFactory jpaQueryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);
return jpaQueryFactory
                .from(qAccVoucherMaster)
                .leftJoin(qAccVoucherMaster.accFinancialYear, qAccFinancialYear).fetchJoin()
                .where(qAccVoucherMaster.voucherDate.between(fromDate, toDate))
                .fetch();
```